# Unable to check if radio button is selected or not: Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, radio-button

I am unable to verify if the radio button I have placed in django templates is check or not. Given below are the HTML and views.py file:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 checkbox" style="margin-left:5px">
     <p class="control-label"><strong>Backlog</strong></p>
     <input type="radio" name="backorNor" value="1"> 
</div>
```

views.py:

```
def get_data(request):
     choice_of_query = request.POST.get("backorNor");
     if choice_of_query == "1":
        mssql_qu = cq_query_backlog.mssql_query.format(sql_product,sql_state,sql_version_reported,sql_op1_drs)
     else:
         mssql_qu = cq_query.mssql_query.format(sql_product,sql_state,sql_version_reported,sql_op1_drs)
```

cq_query_backblog and cq_query are two sql files which I need to run if the radiobutton is checked or not respectively. 
upon printing the type of choice_of_query, I am getting *None*
Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My first impression is that that input is not being posted to your view (so when you do request.POST.get(), it returns None).  Can you double check (by printing request.POST for example) that your input 'backorNor' is being received? Or if you are submitting via a form that the input 'backorNor' is within the form, or if via javascript that you are adding it to the post data

Comment: First a **radio** input should have at least two input fields, one for each choice. Use a type "checkbox" if you only need an on/off switch, i.e. there's only one value. Second is the input inside a form, i.e. does it get submitted at all?